# Fatal utf8_strpos error

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I am receiving the following fatal error on my Joomla 2.5 website: Fatal error: utf8_strpos: Offset must be an integer in /path/to/file/libraries/phputf8/native/core.php on line 66. I recently moved my website to a new host (dedicated Rochen Hosting server) and that is when the error started appearing. The fatal error never appeared on the old hosting provider. I have also been receiving a blank white index.php page intermittently when the website loads, but all of the other pages load with no problem. I am not sure if this issue would be related to the fatal error.

Any assistance with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Mike
Joomla 2.5.4
PHP 5.3.10
MySQL 5.1.61
Apache 2.2.22
Custom Joomla template

Answer (score 0):

Is your current PHP version compatible with the library?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the package php-mbstring isn't installed. Try `sudo yum install php55-mbstring` then `service httpd restart`.